# How to limit the number of concurrent runnable process within an application?

Tags: kernel, scheduler, cgroups

Let's say, an application A has spawned 20 processes. In one time, A is very busy, and 20 processes are in the runnable state. Then cpu load will be high. The responsive time of other application will be hurt by 20 runnable processes..

If there is a way to limit the number of runnable process of a noisy neighborhood, it will mitigate the performance hurt. For examples, only 5 processes are put in the runnable state, other 15 processes are in the interruptible sleep. The cgroups CPU share or CFS quota has little help to this problem. Because cgroups doesn't prevent from putting 20 processes in the runqueue.

Comment: You can use /etc/security/limits.conf to control that behavior check - nproc – max number of processes.

Comment: It is a common case that application creates a process pool according to the number of CPU cores. The application may be insane if I limit the nproc.

Comment: yeah, that's true, other way is taskset, The Linux scheduler will bound to a given CPU affinity and the process will not run on any other CPUs. not sure it is applicable to your issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using cpuset to isolate the noisy neighbor. That brings up another difficult problem - how to allocate CPU cores for each applications efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

To put a hard limit on the noisy neighbor, you can use this:

> ## Ceiling Enforcement Tunable Parameters
>
> ### cpu.cfs_period_us
>
> specifies a period of time in microseconds (µs, represented here as "us") for how regularly a cgroup's access to CPU resources should be reallocated. If tasks in a cgroup should be able to access a single CPU for 0.2 seconds out of every 1 second, set cpu.cfs_quota_us to 200000 and cpu.cfs_period_us to 1000000. The upper limit of the cpu.cfs_quota_us parameter is 1 second and the lower limit is 1000 microseconds.
>
> ## cpu.cfs_quota_us
>
> specifies the total amount of time in microseconds (µs, represented here as "us") for which all tasks in a cgroup can run during one period (as defined by cpu.cfs_period_us). As soon as tasks in a cgroup use up all the time specified by the quota, they are throttled for the remainder of the time specified by the period and not allowed to run until the next period. If tasks in a cgroup should be able to access a single CPU for 0.2 seconds out of every 1 second, set cpu.cfs_quota_us to 200000 and cpu.cfs_period_us to 1000000. Note that the quota and period parameters operate on a CPU basis. To allow a process to fully utilize two CPUs, for example, set cpu.cfs_quota_us to 200000 and cpu.cfs_period_us to 100000.
>   Setting the value in cpu.cfs_quota_us to -1 indicates that the cgroup does not adhere to any CPU time restrictions. This is also the default value for every cgroup (except the root cgroup).

Just limit its usage, for example, for a period of 1000us a quota of 5000us.
This will limit its maximal usage to 5 CPUs without specifying which CPUs exactly.